# Run pyglet.run() while still continuing with loop

Tags: python, pyglet

I am writing a script that creates windows when given a command.

My problem is that calling `pyglet.run()` stops the loop.

I have tried calling `pyglet.run()` in a separate script so it could run simultaneously as well as trying to call it with multiprocessing.

This is the relevant code:

```
import pyglet
windows = []
while True:
    print('Command')
    command = input()
    if command == 'Make Window':
        windows.append(pyglet.window.Window(800, 600, 'My Window'))
        pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: `pyglet.app.run()` runs own loop which has to loop all the time. You could use   [dispatching-events-manually](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/eventloop.html#dispatching-events-manually) in your loop but you use `input()` which stops your loop so it would stop/freeze pyglet too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyglet` has its own loop, defined by `pyglet.app.run()`. Either work with `pyglet` default functions or call new functions in `pyglet`'s loop